# Capacitor charge and discharge circuit with MOSFET

Tags: capacitor, power-electronics

[image]

I want to charge a [capacitor](https://www.mouser.be/datasheet/2/427/220edlc_enycap-1762440.pdf) with a [MOSFET](http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AONR21321.pdf), but it is charging and discharging much slower than I want.

The circuit, which charges in an average of 5 seconds without using a MOSFET, is charged and discharged very slowly in about 3-4 minutes when using a MOSFET. Do you see a problem with the circuit?

The capacitor voltage is 2.7V.

Comment: I used a level drive directly on Q3 and Q5 +/- 5V, no problem. What are your MOSFETs? What is the value of super-capacitor?

Comment: Q3 might need more voltage on its gate. What does the datasheet tell you?

Comment: MOSFET= AONR21321 CAP= MAL222051011E3

Comment: Ok. The capacitor is 5 F. A "little" lower than 100 F in my answer.

Comment: Q3 and Q5 are not the same ... Anyway, you must drive gate "directly" with +/- 10 V, min +/- 5 V)

Comment: What is the MOSFET's Rdson when Vgs is 2V? Probably very high.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that capacitor used is a super-capacitor (100 F, 2.7 V rating).
Here is a theoretical circuit (example) that does it, see the values of resistors needed ...
And that, "hard" switching is also needed.
See the current needed through the capacitor.
Switches needed something as this [MOSFET-P](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nvmfs003p03p8z-d.pdf) [MOSFET-N](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ntmts1d6n10mc-d.pdf)
[image]

Here are the waveforms with a direct drive of the switches (Half H-bridge).
NB: other MOSFETs, don't have original OP.
You can also drive the MOSFETs with two independent signals. Be careful in this case.

[image]

Comment: Why downvote? The answer is "wrong"?

Answer (score 0):

With the capacitor initially completely discharged, the voltage at Q3's source will try to fall to zero when Q3 switches on, a behaviour permitted by the presence of R28 and R29 at its source. I think you intended the source to be at +2V, but it won't be, until the capacitors are fully charged.

You should move R28 and R29 to the drain side of Q3:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBTh6n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This will ensure that Q3's source is always at +2V. Now, if you have a MOSFET with a very, very small \$V_{GS(ON)}\$ (much smaller than -2V), then this transistor can be driven with gate potential either 0V or +2V.

However if Q3's \$V_{GS(ON)}\$ is −1.5V or more negative than that, then you will have to apply a much lower potential at the gate to switch it fully on. You will need to make Q3's gate significantly more negative than 0V to reduce Q3's \$R_{DS(ON)}\$ to its lowest possible resistance.